# Cell Formatting Issue with *.xlsx file in PHP + libxl

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, libxl

I'm having 2 different issues here.

1. Formatting is working fine with filename.xls format but not
   working with filename.xlsx (Microsoft office 2007) file format
2. I tried to switch to filename.xls version but with this version
   our formulas like '*=SUMIFS(tams_database!Q : Q, tams_database!I :
   I,F$1, tams_database!U : U, E1, tams_database!X : X, D1)*' are
   throwing some some warnings like

*PHP Warning:  ExcelSheet::write(): Failed to write cell in row 66, column 13 with error 'incorrect token in formula' in /var/www/portal/www/tcc_v2/app/controllers/DebriefController.php on line 493*

**Note : I have taken care of ExcelBook('','', true/false) w.r.t xlsx & xls files**

---

Please let me know if something wrong with my code.
Thanks

```
<?php 


  $libxl = new ExcelBook("XXXX XXXX","linux-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",true);
  $libxl->loadFile('sample_workbook.xlsx');

  $headerFont   =  $libxl->addFont();
  $headerFont->bold(true); 
  $headerFont->name('Verdana');
  $headerFont->size(10);
  $headerFormat = $libxl->addFormat();
  $headerFormat->fillPattern(ExcelFormat::FILLPATTERN_SOLID);
  $headerFormat->verticalAlign(ExcelFormat::ALIGNV_CENTER);
  $headerFormat->horizontalAlign(ExcelFormat::ALIGNH_CENTER);
  $headerFormat->borderStyle(ExcelFormat::BORDERSTYLE_THIN);
  $headerFormat->patternForegroundColor(ExcelFormat::COLOR_YELLOW);
  $headerFont->color(ExcelFormat::COLOR_BLACK);
  $headerFormat->setFont($headerFont);


  $bodyFont   =  $libxl->addFont();
  $bodyFont->bold(false); 
  $bodyFont->name('Verdana');
  $bodyFont->size(10);
  $bodyFormat = $libxl->addFormat();
  $bodyFormat->fillPattern(ExcelFormat::FILLPATTERN_SOLID);
  $bodyFormat->verticalAlign(ExcelFormat::ALIGNV_CENTER);
  $bodyFormat->horizontalAlign(ExcelFormat::ALIGNH_CENTER);
  $bodyFormat->patternForegroundColor(ExcelFormat::COLOR_WHITE);
  $bodyFormat->borderStyle(ExcelFormat::BORDERSTYLE_THIN);
  $bodyFont->color(ExcelFormat::COLOR_BLACK);
  $bodyFormat->setFont($bodyFont);

  /*-------------------------- Data Sheet End --------------------------*/
  $sheet = $libxl->getSheetByName('sales');

  $productListDetails = $debriefObj->getDebriefExportDataForProductList($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $promotionID);

  $iHeader = 5;
  $iRow = 0;

  if( count($productListDetails) > 0 )
  {
        foreach ($productListDetails as $data) 
        {                             
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, $data['Name'], $headerFormat);
              $iHeader++;                         
        }
  }

  $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 'TOTAL SALES', $headerFormat);
  $iHeader++;

  $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 'HOW MANY CONSUMERS DID YOU APPROACH ?', $headerFormat);
  $iHeader++;

  $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 'DAYS SCHEDULED', $headerFormat);
  $iHeader++;

  $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 'DAYS RUN', $headerFormat);
  $iHeader++;

  $productDetails = $debriefObj->getDebriefExportDataForProducts($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $promotionID);

  $iRow = 1;

  $lastColumnDaysRun = 0;
  $productColStart = 0;

  if( count($productDetails) > 0 )
  {
        foreach ($productDetails as $data) 
        {
              $iHeader = 0;
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, htmlspecialchars_decode($data['Region'], ENT_QUOTES), $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, htmlspecialchars_decode($data['Chain'], ENT_QUOTES), $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, htmlspecialchars_decode($data['Channel'], ENT_QUOTES), $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, htmlspecialchars_decode($data['Outlet'], ENT_QUOTES), $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;
              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, $data['SFDate'], $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;

              $totalSalesStart = $alphabates[$iHeader];
              if( count($productListDetails) > 0 )
              {
                    $productColStart = $iHeader;

                    foreach ($productListDetails as $product) 
                    {                             
                          $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, "SUMIFS(tams_database!Q:Q; tams_database!I:I;".$alphabates[$iHeader]."$1; tams_database!U:U; E$iRow; tams_database!X:X; D$iRow)", $bodyFormat, ExcelFormat::AS_FORMULA);
                          $iHeader++;                         
                    }
              }
              $totalSalesEnd = $alphabates[$iHeader-1];

              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, "SUM($totalSalesStart$iRow, $totalSalesEnd$iRow)", $bodyFormat, , ExcelFormat::AS_FORMULA);
              $iHeader++;


              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, "SUMIFS(tams_database!T:T;  tams_database!U:U; E$iRow; tams_database!X:X; D$iRow)", $bodyFormat, , ExcelFormat::AS_FORMULA);
              $iHeader++;

              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 1, $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;

              $sheet->write($iRow, $iHeader, 1, $bodyFormat);
              $iHeader++;

              $iRow++;
        }

        $lastColumnDaysRun = $iHeader;
  }
```

Comment: SUMIFS isn't supported in BIFF format (xls) files; it was only introduced to MS Excel 2007 for xlsx files

Comment: @MarkBaker : Ohh, wasn't aware of that...thanks Mark :)